# Build a site in a localhost environment and view that site on another computer

Tags: xampp, localhost

We created a site on a computer through Joomla in the localhost environment (xampp). Now I want to see the same site on another computer. How can I do this?(**Computers are not connected in any way**)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to achieve this and as they are not on the same network or intranet but connected through internet then you will be able to access it through a domain or IP address. I have done it before and its cool and can be achieved in minutes.
First you need to change the virtualhost file.
File can be found in `Xampp->apache->conf->extra->httpd-vhosts.conf`

Here you need to specify a domain name which will point to your joomla folder.

You need to append this at the bottom of that file and change the variables as per your site. Remember if you have a https site then you need to change `VirtualHost *:80` to `VirtualHost *:443`

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/joomla"
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ErrorLog "logs/example.com-error.log"
    CustomLog "logs/example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

After making those changes you need to restart Apache from Xampp control panel so that the changes can take effect.

Its not over yet as the changes are only effective in your PC not on internet. So you need to point your specific domain to your PC IP address if you have a fixed IP or you can also use afraid dot org, dynu dot com, no-ip etc if you have dynamic IP addresses. For dynamic IP you need to change the name servers accordingly as per different service providers in your domain control panel.

Note: It may take some time for the changes to take effect. Around 48 hours max for DNS propagation.